# Build Ubuntu VM using mirror

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, mirrors

In kvm, using virt-install I can create centos images using this parameter in my virt install command.

-l http://mirror.umd.edu/centos/6/os/x86_64/

```
Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                             |  798 B     00:00 ... 
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                               | 7.7 MB     00:00 ... 
Retrieving file initrd.img...                            |  62 MB     00:07 ...
```

Files get fetched from the mirror, kvm builds and installs the vm using my specifications. I'd like to know the equivalent of that mirror in ubuntu?

Here are few mirrors I digged out but I can't find a working one with this path, curling through the mirrors, I'm not finding treeinfo, vmlinuz, initrd.img files.

http://mirror.uoregon.edu/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/installer-amd64/
http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/installer-i386/

Any pointers?

Comment: http://mirror.uoregon.edu/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/cdrom/ has a tree similar the one you refer (no .treeinfo)

Comment: please answer question bellow, so I give you answer credit. thanks and just for anyone who is curious about this in the future

Comment: So using that url your images are correctly created? I will check if I can find a more generic answer to this: it is very odd that even [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/CreateGuests) there is nothing pointing out how to use a mirror.

Comment: # sudo virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n $NAME -r 2048 --vcpus=2 --disk path=/drives/A/images/$NAME.img,size=20 -l $LINK --vnc --noautoconsole --os-type linux --accelerate --network=bridge:br0 --network=bridge:br1 --hvm
ERROR    Error validating install location: Could not find an installable distribution at 'http://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-amd64/current/images/cdrom/'

Comment: its missing the .treeinfo file, i'm trying to see if I could trick my way around that. http://backdrift.org/ubuntu-lucid-10-04-cobbler-kickstart-setup-how-to